# Array that takes the three lowest numbers and outputs them

Tags: arrays

I'm kind of new to programming and just trying to figure out how to solve this problem. I need to take an array, find the three lowest numbers, put them into a second array and then print them out. I know how to copy elements from one array to another but not sure about finding the lowest. This what I have so far:

```
int[] array1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int[] array2 = new int[array1.length];

     for (int i=0; i<array1.length;i++){
     array2[i] = array1[i]; } System.out.print(Arrays.toString(array2));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array and copy the first 3 elements into a new array, e.g.:

```
int[] array = new int[]{1,5,7,0,8,2,3};
Arrays.sort(array);
int newArray[] = new int[3];
for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
    newArray[i] = array[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Comment: Sort? Java's `Arrays.sort` offers `O(n log(n))` performance. The better way is to loop the array and get the smallest 3 elements with complexity `O(n)`

Comment: Plus, we're changing the order of the array (which might be important, we don't know).

Comment: As OP is new to programming, it will be easier to use this approach rather than declaring and manipulating 3 variables. Also, we can use `System.arrayCopy` if main array needn't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Java 8:

```
int[] answer = Arrays.stream(array).sorted().limit(3).toArray();
```

Comment: This is better since we don't change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

A more optimized way would be to use [Guava Ordering](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html).

```
final Integer [] numbers = new Integer[]{23,23,24,2,42,4,235,456,45,7};
final Iterable<Integer> integerIterable = Iterables.cycle(numbers);
final List<Integer> bottom3 = Ordering.natural().leastOf(integerIterable, 3);
```

It uses an O(n) algorithm using only one pass and O(k) additional memory, k being 3 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the whole array is one way to do it but because the size of the array may be unknown and sorting can take more time it may be better to bubble sort the first 3 smallest integers to the top. For example:

```
int[] arr = {9, 5, 2, 1, 0, 5, -10, 25, 45, -25, 90, -72};
int temp;
for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    for(int i = arr.length-1; i >= 1; i--) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[i-1]) {
            temp = arr[i - 1];
            arr[i - 1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
/* Result:
-72
-25
-10
*/
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I also have to do it the other way around where I need to find the top three numbers. I could probably use this for the as well, right? With altering some of the code of course.

Comment: Yep, you could use the same array and method except change `if(arr[i] < arr[i-1])` to `if(arr[i] > arr[i-1])`